# JavaFX: How to listen for events on non-UI object

Tags: java, events, javafx, dispatcher

I've got a Model I call BlahModel.  It's referenced by BlahController(BlahModel blahModel).  My goal is that BlahModel can dispatch and event

Event.fireEvent(blahModel,...)

Which is heard by the BlahController to kick off jan action.  As of now, I've been using an Observable Integer of somekind, and watching that but of course that doesn't feel right.

My question is, what on earth should a non-GUI component do to implement buildEventDispatchChain so other non-GUI components can listen to it.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use something like [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html)?

Comment: I pretty much always find I can refactor this and think of it as some state of the model changing. (The model is just supposed to represent data, after all.) Then just represent that model state with a JavaFX observable property, and observing it in the usual JavaFX way seems very natural. In the very worst case you create an `enum` and wrap it in an `ObjectProperty`, (this is, for example, how the `Task` class works) but that often turns out to be an intuitive approach.

Comment: Speaking of `Task`, you could check how they manage the `setOnSucceeded` etc in the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/298ec4ec6b35/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/concurrent/Task.java). (Event management starts around line 1240, and uses an [`EventHelper` class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/298ec4ec6b35/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/concurrent/EventHelper.java).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventDispatchChain` is designed for events bubbling through a nested hierarchy (e.g. scene graph)—probably not what you want/need.

[ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX)'s `EventStream` is an event analogy to `ObservableValue`:

```
import org.reactfx.EventSource;
import org.reactfx.EventStream;
import org.reactfx.Subscription;

class BlahModel {

    private EventSource<Integer> events = new EventSource<>();

    public EventStream<Integer> events() { return events; }

    void foo() {
        // fire event
        events.push(42);
    }
}

class BlahController {
    private final Subscription eventSubscription;

    BlahController(BlahModel blahModel) {
        eventSubscription = blahModel.events().subscribe(
                i -> System.out.println("Received event " + i));
    }

    public void dispose() {
        eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```